# Request.ServerVariables.AllKeys does not contains all the keys

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

We are using Request.ServerVariables to read a specific header value added by a proxy in the request header.

We can get and read the searched value using

```
Request.ServerVariables.Get(myKey)
// or
Request.ServerVariables[myKey]
```

but we notice that when we loop over the keys with

```
foreach (string key in Request.ServerVariables.AllKeys)
...
```

we don't get the searched key !

Inside the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525396%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) we can read :

> The ServerVariables collection retrieves the values of **predetermined**
>   environment variables and request header information.

So is this correct to say that Request.ServerVariables.AllKeys does not contain all the keys and that we have to use the indexer or the get method to test if the key exists ?

Comment: Here's a complete [list(IIS Server Variables)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602.aspx) over all the possible keys in ServerVariables. Which are not available?

Comment: so we only see predetermined variables ? that's what I want to be sure.

Comment: I came across this today and find it totally puzzling, to say the least. [Documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602.aspx) variables such as `HTTP_URL` or `UNENCODED_URL` are *nowhere to be found* when enumerating `Request.ServerVariables`, yet accessing them directly like `Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_URL"]` returns a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [full list of variables can be found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). If you know the specific variables you're after, it would be more efficient to simply request these that enumerate the full collection anyway.

If you just debug in your web application, you will see the full list, and you can't add to this list in code (easily) as far as I know.

[image]

Comment: it just for debug, and i don't get the full list that's why i'm surprised!

Comment: You don't get the 49 or so listed? or do you mean you can't see specific variables that you have sent via the header?

Comment: I get the 49. I don't get a specific value sent inside the header with AllKeys. I get the specific header value only using the get method or the indexer.

Comment: That's all you will see using `Allkeys`, it's only a predefined collection.

Comment: thanks, that's the confirmation I was looking for : With Allkeys you don't see all the keys.

Answer (score -1):

I thing you miss Name attribute of input element

for example 
you con't get the value of bellow control using `Request.ServerVariables.Get(myKey);`

```
<input type='text' value='Indian' />
```

you use `<input name ='country' type='text' value='Indian' />` and

```
Request.ServerVariables.Get('country');
```

Comment: i don't submit a form and don't try to get an input value